# Why is it necessary to place self as a parameter for method decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

For module-level functions, this code holds:

```
def dec(f):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

@dec
def foo(arg1):
    pass
```

When decorating methods however, all of a sudden you'll have to have one parameter to catch the instance.

```
def dec(f):
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @dec
    def foo(self, arg1):
        pass
```

Why is that the case? What's so special about `self` that `*args` isn't able to catch it? After all isn't it just another positional argument?
Also, how is it(`self`) passed into the inner `wrap` function?

For the first case, it's simply equivalent to `foo = dec(foo)`. From what I've learned with closures, before `foo` is passed as an argument to the decorator. It creates an enclosure with `__closure__`, so it's able to retain whatever arguments were passed to `foo`.

Why is it that when it comes to methods then, apparently `self` doesn't seem to be part of the `__closure__`?

Comment: Funny, if you use the decorator of the first example (so without redefining dec(f) in method-level), then it works inside the class as well, without the calling of "self". `@dec def foo(arg1): pass` will then be callable as Test.foo('bar')..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that the case? What's so special about `self` that `*args` isn't able to catch it?

This question is based on a premise that's flawed. As a matter of fact, `*args` can include `self`, both with and without decorators. This is illustrated by the following two examples.

Without decorators:

```
class Test(object):

  def foo(self, *args):
    return (self,) + args

  def bar(*args):  # for the purposes of illustration
    return args

t = Test()
print(t.foo(42))
print(t.bar(42))
```

With decorators:

```
def dec(f):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

class Test(object):

    @dec
    def foo(self, arg1):
        return (self, arg1)

t = Test()
print(t.foo(42))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best stated by the creator of Python himself:

http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

The main two points are:

> There's a pretty good argument to make that requiring explicit 'self' in the parameter list reinforces the theoretical equivalency between these two ways of calling a method.

and

> Another argument for keeping explicit 'self' in the parameter list is the ability to dynamically modify a class by poking a function into it, which creates a corresponding method.

Comment: Uh... I'm actually asking a completely different question, I might have to reword my question a bit but It's mainly about decorators and closures.